# Find the pointwise limit and the uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = x(1-x^n)$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Find the pointwise limit and the uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = x(1-x^n)$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+2}$ where for both functions$f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $

For the first function, I found the pointwise limit to be: $ x $ for $x \in [0, 1)$ and $0$ if $x=1$

To determine uniform convergence,
 $$f_n'(x) = (1-x^n) + x(-nx^{n-1}) = 1-x^n -nx^n = 1 - (1+n)x^n$$

I am having trouble moving forward determining uniform convergence.

For the second function, the pointwise limit is x for all x. I also do not how to go on and prove uniform convergence

Comment: A useful theorem: [if $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is continuous.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) That will take care of the first.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

A useful theorem: [if $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is continuous.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) That will take care of the first:

- The pointwise limit of $(f_n)_n$ is $f$
- if $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly, then its uniform limit is the same as its pointwise limit
- for every $n$, $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$
- but... $f$ here is not exactly continuous on $[0,1]$, is it?

---

As for the second: for every $x\in[0,1]$, and all $n$
$$
f(x) - f_n(x) = \frac{(n+2)x}{n+2} - \frac{n x}{n+2}  = \frac{2x}{n+2}
$$
so that
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1] }\lvert f(x) - f_n(x)\rvert
= \sup_{x\in[0,1] }\left\lvert \frac{2x}{n+2}\right\rvert
=  \frac{2}{n+2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
so you can now conclude about uniform convergence.

Comment: So, you are saying that the first is not uniform convergent?

Comment: @kt046172 Indeed, that's what I am saying.

Comment: Also, does a discontinuous limit function imply non-uniform convergence?

Comment: @kt046172 Yes, this is what the above theorem says. If you have a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a discontinuous function, then the convergence cannot be uniform.